# How to check the multiple indicdual radio buttons in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

In my page so many group radio buttons are there like this.

first div "Request-1" only default checked.After button click I am calling the below jQuery function to assign selected value to other div radio buttons.

```
if ($("#Request-1:input:checked").length > 0) {

            $("#Request-2").attr('checked', 'checked');
            $("#Request-3").attr('checked', 'checked');
            $("#Request-4").attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
        else if ($("#DRequest-1:input:checked").length > 0) {
            $("#DRequest-2").attr('checked', 'checked');
            $("#DRequest-3").attr('checked', 'checked');
            $("#DRequest-4").attr('checked', 'checked');

        }
```

But only #REquest-4 is checking other radio buttons are not checking .Please tell me how to check all radio buttons .

```
 <div id="choose-1">
<input id="Request-1"  type="radio" name="request-type"  checked="checked"/>Data REquest



     <input id="DRequest-1"  type="radio" name="request-type"/>D Request Data
    </div>
 <div id="choose-2">
    <input id="Request-2"  type="radio" name="request-type" />Data REquest

      <input id="DRequest-2"  type="radio" name="request-type"/>D Request Data
    </div>
 <div id="choose-3">
    <input id="Request-3"  type="radio" name="request-type" />Data REquest

      <input id="DRequest-13"  type="radio" name="request-type"/>D Request Data
    </div>
 <div id="choose-4">
    <input id="Request-4"  type="radio" name="request-type"  checked="checked"/>Data REquest

      <input id="DRequest-4"  type="radio" name="request-type"/>D Request Data
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `radio buttons` and they are in a same `group request-type` so only one can be selected in this case

To work you need to use `checkboxes` inplace of `radios`

Then try to use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) and merge all selectors separated by a `,` like

```
if ($("#Request-1:checked").length > 0) {
   $("#Request-2, #Request-3, #Request-4").prop('checked', true);
}
else if ($("#DRequest-1:checked").length > 0) {
   $("#DRequest-2, #DRequest-3, #DRequest-4").prop('checked', true);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/KyPyv/)

If you need to toggle checkboxes on changing their status then try this,

```
$('#Request-1').on('change',function(){
    $("#Request-2, #Request-3, #Request-4").prop('checked', this.checked);    
}).change();
$('#DRequest-1').on('change',function(){
    $("#DRequest-2, #DRequest-3, #DRequest-4").prop('checked', this.checked);    
}).change();
```

**Checkbox** [change demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/KyPyv/1/)

Again you need to use radios then you need to change radio buttons grouping like,

```
<div id="choose-1">
    <input id="Request-1" type="radio" name="request-type" checked="checked" />Data REquest
    <input id="DRequest-1" type="radio" name="request-type" />D Request Data</div>
<div id="choose-2">
    <input id="Request-2" type="radio" name="request-type-2" />Data REquest
    <input id="DRequest-2" type="radio" name="request-type-2" />D Request Data</div>
<div id="choose-3">
    <input id="Request-3" type="radio" name="request-type-3" />Data REquest
    <input id="DRequest-3" type="radio" name="request-type-3" />D Request Data</div>
<div id="choose-4">
    <input id="Request-4" type="radio" name="request-type-4" />Data REquest
    <input id="DRequest-4" type="radio" name="request-type-4" />D Request Data
</div>
```

**Radio** [change demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/KyPyv/3/)

Comment: same issue last div radio button REquest-4 only is checked remaining radio buttons are not checking.in above desing each div is in seperate tab.i mean one div in one tab,next div in aonther tab like that.4 th tab div radio button only checking ,when click on 4 th tab.

Comment: in my design each div in seperate tab.when click on 1 st tab i am calling the above javascript ,based on that radio selection in first tab assinging values to next tab.but 4 th tab last radio button only checking using the above code.

Comment: thanks due to same radio groups .i changed each div radio buttons to different groups,resolvd the issue.